# Trying to get data from spreadsheet & show them using UiApp functions but I get last matching entry only, how to make GAS wait for input per result?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Still New to GAS and programming in general. What I'm trying to do is:

1. if a row has Column 48/AW AND column 50 empty it should grab data from a few cells in that row.
2. Arrange and show the collected data in a neat summary/report made using UiApp functions.
3. Grab values using radio buttons and text input fields and save said values back into AW.

This is my code so far:

```
function TestFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet_ID").getActiveSheet();
var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // This gets ALL data within the sheet - not very useful if you need only snippets
var ELTSummarizer = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(480).setWidth(640).setTitle('Unreviewed Applicant');
var CandidateInfoGrid = ELTSummarizer.createGrid(3, 2);
var panel = ELTSummarizer.createVerticalPanel();
var button = ELTSummarizer.createButton('Press Me');

panel.add(CandidateInfoGrid);
panel.add(button);
ELTSummarizer.add(panel);

for(n = 2; n < values.length; ++n){  // Make a finite loop that reads every row found in column AW (the 48th column in the sheet) data will be stored in the variable called Cell
   var cell = values[n][48] ;       //n = row number, 48 = Column AW where comments are saved - x is the index of the column starting from 0
   CandidateInfoGrid.setWidget(0, 0, ELTSummarizer.createLabel('Name:'+ values[n][1]));
   CandidateInfoGrid.setWidget(0, 1, ELTSummarizer.createLabel('Row#:'+ n));

  if (values[n][50] == '' && cell == '') {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    spreadsheet.show(ELTSummarizer);
  }   
 }
}
```

What currently happens is that the correct data (apparently) is found but then I see the browser refresh again and again and it keeps overwriting the results until the loop reaches the last matching row and that's the one I see. So my questions are:

- Is there a way to make the Cycle stop at each result?
- Is this even the correct way to achieve what I want to? Is there another way I can get this data showing up with the ability to input data that will be written back to the same row?

As usual, any help will be appreciated and thank you for reading this far!

P.S. I've tried using the UI Service guides/examples by Google and all of them ended in "Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred" messages - in some cases they still worked though. Not sure why it does that.

Comment: if you want to break out of a for loop, use break;

Comment: the behavior you describe seems to be logical, you should store the values in an array variable and populate your grid with these values after the loop has completed and then use spreadsheet.show(ELTSummarizer); to show the result.

Comment: Oh wow I'd almost given up on this! Thanks for replying teatimer and Serge! 
@Sergeinsas I guess my main issue then is that I don't know how to store just the results found within the 'if' in an array - I thought the 'var values' line did just that? Sorry if this is all basic stuff, I'm more teacher than programmer. Thank for reading!

Answer (score 0):

following your comment, here is a version that shows the results one by one in your UI and has a button to continue the process... is that the idea you had ?
not sure I understood exactly what you wanted.

```
function TestFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aIMzaaHR5czjc2gl0ifHI7SCt8ihw_Y4rwuCgCVhvt8").getSheets()[0];// get first sheet in this SS
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // This gets ALL data within the sheet - not very useful if you need only snippets
  var ELTSummarizer = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(480).setWidth(640).setTitle('Unreviewed Applicant');
  var CandidateInfoGrid = ELTSummarizer.createGrid(3, 2);
  var panel = ELTSummarizer.createVerticalPanel();
  var handler = ELTSummarizer.createServerHandler('continueLoop').addCallbackElement(panel)
  var button = ELTSummarizer.createButton('next match').addClickHandler(handler);
  CandidateInfoGrid.setWidget(0, 0, ELTSummarizer.createLabel('Name:').setId('labelName'));
  CandidateInfoGrid.setWidget(1, 0, ELTSummarizer.createLabel('Row#:').setId('labelRow'));
  var pos = ELTSummarizer.createTextBox().setName('pos').setId('pos');// .setVisible(false); // uncomment this to hide the position counter box
  panel.add(CandidateInfoGrid);
  panel.add(button).add(pos);
  ELTSummarizer.add(panel);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var position = 2

  for(n = position; n < values.length; ++n){  // Make a finite loop that reads every row found in column AW (the 48th column in the sheet) data will be stored in the variable called Cell
    var cell = values[n][48] ;       //n = row number, 48 = Column AW where comments are saved - x is the index of the column starting from 0    
    if (values[n][50] == '' && cell == '') {
      position = n;
      pos.setText(n);
      ELTSummarizer.getElementById('labelName').setText('Name : '+ values[n][1]);
      ELTSummarizer.getElementById('labelRow').setText('Row# : '+ n);   
      break;
    }   
  }
  spreadsheet.show(ELTSummarizer);
}

function continueLoop(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aIMzaaHR5czjc2gl0ifHI7SCt8ihw_Y4rwuCgCVhvt8").getSheets()[0];// get first sheet in this SS
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // This gets ALL data within the sheet - not very useful if you need only snippets
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var labelName = app.getElementById('labelName');
  var labelRow = app.getElementById('labelRow');
  var pos = app.getElementById('pos');
  var position = Number(e.parameter.pos);
  for(n = position; n < values.length; ++n){  // Make a finite loop that reads every row found in column AW (the 48th column in the sheet) data will be stored in the variable called Cell
    var cell = values[n][48] ;       //n = row number, 48 = Column AW where comments are saved - x is the index of the column starting from 0    
    if (values[n][50] == '' && cell == '') {
      app.getElementById('labelName').setText('Name : '+ values[n][1]);
      app.getElementById('labelRow').setText('Row# : '+ n);
      n++;
      pos.setText(n);
      break;
  }   
  }
  return app;
}
```

the continueLoop function should handle the input of your text and write that content to the sheet... still some work to do on this script...
I would do it in a separate function using parameters but if it's only one field you can integrate it in the same function.

Hoping that helps

[image]